# Window Stay without drilling into window

Tags: windows, usa, window-frame

I have an awning type window that hinges at the top of the window (the gold bar on the right is rusty, stiff, and the frame doesn't even have the holes where it would be screwed into):

[image: awning window]

I have a cat and am trying to limit how much the window can be open. I 3D printed [this clamp](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1673030) and thought to use the knob to hold the window open. This kind of worked for my solution but the problem is that the wind can blow the window open further and also the clamp only lets the window open a couple inches, which isn't much. Here is a photo of how it looks:

[image]

Is there a window stay that would work for my solution that does not require me to drill into the frame/window?

Comment: Country? This isn't a style of window we tend to see in the US, as far as I know. You could probably design and print a double clamp, attaching both to frame and to window...

Comment: @keshlam I'm in the United States 

Comment: The stays are designed to limit how far the window will go so you dont fall out or so a burglar cant come in.  They dont tend to be adjustable and resistant to wind.

Comment: Is it your property or rented? That type of suicide window was outlawed in the UK decades ago & I'd be surprised if it isn't the same for the rest of the world. So, either you or the landlord need to fix it fast & permanently - with a shorter stay than the original. The maximum opening on those these days, even old ones that have been retrofitted, is 2 - 3".

Comment: Does the cat open the window?

Comment: @Huesmann No but he will jump on the window sill occasionally however he's not very coordinated so I am trying to prevent any major accidents (We are 15 stories up)

Comment: I think in your case I'd be thinking of getting some 2" welded wire fabric strips.  You could form a Z-strap for the bottom of the window and L-strap for the sides,  Fasten one leg of each strip to the window frame (YMMV), and the other leg of the Z-strap should keep the window from opening too far.  Might look like junk, but it'd keep the kitty safe.

Comment: @Huesmann - please don't put answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D printing to the rescue. I found [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5249535) model on Thingiverse and it has been doing a good job. I superglued the prints to the window. When it's time to move, that's future me's problem.

[image: window stay]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a type of window mechanism I'm familiar with, but I think I'm seeing what looks like a jointed stay of some sort at the right side of the window, though it's hanging loose rather than attached to the movable window. See red circle:

[image]

So I'd suggest looking for something which can install using the screw holes used/implied by that. There might be one on the other side too.

Comment: I am not sure what this stay was attached to because the window does not have the 2 screw holes. It has become very stiff/rusty as well so I just use it to prop the window open but the window will occasionally blow it back down.

Comment: Can't advise you better since I'm not there to look at it, but since it exists it MUST have been attached to something at some point. Best suggestion I've got is to find a similar window elsewhere in your building where this is intact and see how it was attached there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a sliding, locking stay.

[image]

These come in a myriad designs, but essentially all prevent the window from opening too far & can be locked down to anything less than maximum too.

You will need to drill both sill & window, though. I don't see how you can avoid that & have something stable.